# QGis Python featurerequest with lists

Tags: qgis-plugins, features, query, select-by-attribute

I want to select some features and do some actions to this selected features.
Something like *if attribute in field a is = abc than do something*. But the selection will not fit. As written in https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html i have tried:

```
query = ' "fieldname" = \ 'attribute\ ' '
request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(query)
for feature in self.layer.getFeatures(request):
   'do something'
```

Fieldname and attributs are arrays and i want to iterate them. That's the Problem!
How can i write the query in the correct syntax?

What i need issomething like:

```
query = " ' " + ' " ' + fieldname[i] + ' " ' + ' = ' + '\' + " ' " +  attribute[j] + ' \ ' + " '' "
```

or

```
query = chr(39) + chr(34) + fieldname[0] + chr(34) + chr(39) + chr(61) + chr(92) + chr(39) + attribute[j] + chr(92) + chr(39) + chr(39)
```

Both will not work.
Any Idea?